# How to get List element after `[[ ]]` operation

Tags: list-manipulation

How to get the first and second element in every last column from every row?
eg. `{{7,8}, {3,3}}`

```
a = {
   {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}},
   {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}}
   };
```

I use `a[[All,3]]` get

```
{{7, 8, 9}, {3, 3, 3}}
```

A bit far from the requirements `{{7,8}, {3,3}}`

Any comments will be appreciate!

Comment: `Map[Most,a[[All,3]]]` or `Most/@a[[All,3]]`

Comment: @Bill Thank you

Comment: a[[All,-1,1;;2]] where "-1" is for the "last column"

Comment: @andre314 Best answer! Thank you so much